# Deploying asp.net core project to IIS via TeamCity with different environments (UAT, Release)

Tags: asp.net-core, teamcity

I'm new to asp.net core and I'm trying to deploy the project into UAT and Release environment (server) via TeamCity.

With the help of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1h3rWGKt44 I can build the project no problem, but it's the next step where I can publish and deploy into different environments.

NOTE: I can publish from Visual Studio 2017 having EnvironmentName set up, which will generate the , which then in turn picks up appsettings.uat.json file etc.  But we want to do this via Team city like what we've done with all our other MVC and webforms projects.

Could anyone out there help please?